# Switch between two speakers when two motherboard jacks

Tags: audio, motherboard, speakers, kvm-switch

I've seen other questions where they only have one motherboard jack, however I have 4 audio jack outputs as seen in this image here:

[image: Z170-A Back IO]

I can plug in the speaker to the orange port lets say as a centre speaker and have it run, however only if I let it be a left, right and centre setup with my headphones, I just want them to run separately which should be perfectly reasonable with software, I just don't know how.

I currently have my headphones plugged in in the pink and green jacks and then I have the others spare, I believe the speaker is plugged in in the orange. How can I make it so I can switch from speakers to headphones without any hardware?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't.
Blue & pink are switchable, separate inputs for Mic & Line level.

Green, black & orange are part of a single output, for 5.1 surround sound.
Green is front left/right
Black is rear left/right
Orange is centre channel & sub-woofer.

If your output is only stereo [2.0], then only the green will be used, 2.1 will add the sub channel.

Your only real option is if you also have the green/blue/pink duplicated on your computer's front panel. That is likely to be designed more for a headset & will probably have smart switching. When the headset is plugged in the speakers will switch off & vice versa.

Your third alternative could be to use the digital output - the black square with chamfered corners & the little grey door - this is a light-pipe digital output, switchable from your sound control panel & can carry either stereo or 5.1 audio... though you would need an external converter/amp to decode it.

Comment: Firstly, I don't use the front HD audio as my headphones have a massive 2m cable and when I plug headphones in I get a lot of hissing and crackling, presumably from EMI. Can you think of any reason this may be and how to fix? Also, can you recommend a good DAC, I already have a optical cable somewhere I believe, It's not going to some amazing speakers, just average ones. Thanks. ^^